# Lua_hook and lua_Debug->event

Tags: c++, c, lua

I'm  trying to learn lua and building a virtual machine in c++, I want to write a debugging class, to make my life easier. I'm actually blocked because I don't understand how the callbacks are done, here is my code :

```
 //Im here adding my fct to a global map.
 void Debugger::setFctHook(void)                
{                                              
  g_hookers[LUA_MASKCALL] = HookCall;          
  g_hookers[LUA_MASKRET] = HookRet;            
  g_hookers[LUA_HOOKTAILRET] = HookRet;        
  g_hookers[LUA_MASKLINE] = HookLine;          
  g_hookers[LUA_MASKCOUNT] = HookCount;                                         
}
```

Here is my constructor :

```
Debugger::Debugger(VirtualMachine &vm, uint count)         
  : VM_(vm), count_(count)                                 
 {                                                          
  setFctHook();                                            
  if (vm.isFonctionnal())                                  
   {                                                      
     vm.addDebugger(this);                                
     lua_sethook(vm.getLua(), HookEvents, 0, count_);     
   }                                                      
}
```

and my setter :

```
 void    Debugger ::setHook(int hookMask) const                   
 {                                                               
   std::cout << hookMask << "SETHOOOOOOOOOK" << std::endl;       
    lua_sethook(VM_.getLua(), HookEvents, hookMask, count_);      
 }
```

Here is my Central hook  :

```
static void HookEvents(lua_State *lua, lua_Debug *debug) 
{                                                        
  std::map<int, fctHook>::iterator it;  
  std::cout << debug->event << std::endl;
  it = g_hookers.find(debug->event);   
  if (it != g_hookers.end())    
  {    
    std::cout << "First: " << it->first << std::endl;
    it->second(lua);              
  }                     
}
```

The problem is that the value show in my setter differs from the value printed in my central function hook, I tried many defines and I dont see any logic in the different values.

```
 Result : 
 8 SETHOOOOOOOOOK // received on my setter.
 3 // received on my central hook
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, the problem is that my map has bad values on it, the correct defines for the hooks are :

```
void Debugger::setFctHook(void)                
{                                              

 g_hookers[LUA_HOOKCALL] = HookCall;      
 g_hookers[LUA_HOOKRET] = HookRet;        
 g_hookers[LUA_HOOKTAILRET] = HookRet;    
 g_hookers[LUA_HOOKLINE] = HookLine;      
 g_hookers[LUA_HOOKCOUNT] = HookCount;
}
```

Comment: Any difference? Why the former one is wrong?